# Can't see values from dropdownbox

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am trying to create a simple dropdown list on riot. The issue is that I can't see the title and value from the dropdown.
My code is:

```
  <select id="inputType" >
    <option each={item in items} value={item.value} >{item.title}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Could you post your `items` array? I was able to get it to work on the [link] http://riotjs.com/play/ page with 
`<script>
    this.items = [
      { value: '1', title: 'a' },
      { value: '2', title: 'b' },
      { value: '3', title: 'c' }
    ]</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was very simple I did a var items and should be done this.items